# Вопрос пожарных №2

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология, семантика, общие-вопросы

Как правильно говорить/писать в сфере **пожарной охраны РФ** / **ДСНС України** термин:
**пострадавший/постраждалий** (укр. мова, *прим. ред.*) или **потерпевший/потерпілий** (*укр. мова, прим. ред.*)?

Заранее прошу прощения у всех вас за вопрос по украинскому языку!!!
Я сам из Харькова, поэтому интересуют оба варианта!

Прошу еще раз прощения за неформат!!!

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, на русском это погорелец

Answer (score 0):

У меня есть своя теория по этому поводу!

Представьте себе: После ДТП вы видите лежащего на дороге человека. Визуально наблюдаете у него переломы конечностей, ссадины и т. д. Он кричит  и стонет от боли... Представили?

Так вот, моя логика заставляет меня считать его  **ПОСТРАДАВШИМ**, так как он **страдает**. А если бы он **терпел**, то был бы **ПОТЕРПЕВШИМ**!

Вот такая у меня интересная логика, с тонкими нотками шизофрении!!!

Answer (score 0):

Пострадавший. И то не всякий, а только тот, которому причинен физический ущерб (т. е. ущерб здоровью). Материальный ущерб в категорию пострадавших не переводит.
Ну а "потерпевший" - это термин уголовного права, тут, конечно, может быть, например, вариант с поджогом, тогда "потерпевший" возможно. Но это отдельный разговор.
Комментировать украинский вариант не хочу принципиально. "Не для здесь" это.